# How can I record vocal and music clearly with speaker? (not headset)

Tags: audio, echo, audio-recording

i want to record vocal and music played in android speaker
recored music is unclear.
is there any way??
I tried recording only vocal and mixing orignal music with headset.
but i want to make it with speaker not headset.

thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is possible but I did find a guide to help from google.

https://itstillworks.com/record-audio-computer-speakers-7341043.html

Good luck!